# Add a break line between concatenated strings in VB.net

Tags: .net, text, textbox, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate the output of various functions into a textbox, but it all comes up in one biiig line. How can I insert break lines in between the variables? I have something like this:

```
Me.TextBox.text = output1 + output2
```

And I would like to have something like this:

```
Me.TextBox.text = output1 + ENTER + output2
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) read-only variable is what you want to use. There's also `vbCrLf`, but this is for legacy purposes and *not* environment-dependant.

Try the following:

```
Me.TextBox.Text = output1 + Environment.NewLine + output2
```

Answer (score 6):

```
Me.TextBox.text = output1 & Environment.NewLine & output2
```

Also use & to concat strings vb.net, + is legacy support

Comment: & is just as legacy.  There are some good reason to prefer '+' now and then.

Comment: In fact using **&** is the [prefered way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te2585xw.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Environment.NewLine is usually the preferred method.  It'll produce a carriage return & line feed for Windows systems and a line feed only for Unix systems...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Also note that you can use vbCrLf from the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace which will *always* return a carriage return and line feed together.