# In VB.net, how to show 2 consecutive messages (with ShowAsync) on the right order?

Tags: .net, vb.net, async-await

I want to display 2 consecutive messages "A" and "B" in a certain order. As we need to use ShowAsync, the result seems randomized. We get sometimes A before B, and sometimes B before A. How to solve this?

```
    ...

    MsgBox("A")

    MsgBox("B")

    ...

    Public Async Sub MsgBox(msg$)

Dim dialog = New Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(msg$)

Await dialog.ShowAsync()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the function is `Async`:

```
Public Async Sub MsgBox(msg$)
```

If you want to wait for the first invocation to complete before beginning the second, you need to `Await` it:

```
Await MsgBox("A")
Await MsgBox("B")
```

(I'm surprised there isn't a compiler warning telling you that `MsgBox` isn't being awaited...)

Note: I'm *much* more familiar with C# than with VB, but I wonder if there's another problem here.  Shouldn't `MsgBox` return a `Task`?  If this is the VB equivalent of `async void` then that's another problem entirely and you'll want to correct that.  Since that wouldn't be await-able (and wouldn't provide any way for consuming code to handle error conditions).

Comment: @loulou: As you can probably see, the code in that comment is *entirely* unreadable.  It's also not clear at all what you're trying to ask in that comment.  If you have further clarification on your question, please add it to the question itself.

Comment: @loulou: Google is surprisingly helpful with such things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411313/add-a-break-line-between-concatenated-strings-in-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

I have the answer, maybe there are another ones.
 Private Sub BT_Test_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BT_Test.Click
 Test()
 End Sub
 Async Sub Test()
 Await MsgBox("1")
 Await MsgBox("2")
 End Sub
 Public Async Function MsgBox(msg$) As Task
 Dim dialog = New Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(msg$)
 Await dialog.ShowAsync()
 End Function
 
We may also use Sub Async BT_Test_Click without using the sub Test.
So, not totally easy to understand and solve the asynchronous/synchronous methods !