# Sorting Numbers in Textbox in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I need help with my program I want my output box to be in ascending order like:

0

1

2

3

4

5

6 and so on

but my output is like this 1234567890 and so on.

Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim count As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, count) Then
            Dim strNumbers As String = ""
            For x As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                strNumbers &= x
            Next
            TextBox2.Text = strNumbers
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `strNumbers &= x` --> `strNumbers &= Environment.NewLine & x`. Alternatively, you could just do `TextBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable.Range(0, count))` and get rid of the `For` loop altogether.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a break line between concatenated strings in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411313/add-a-break-line-between-concatenated-strings-in-vb-net)

Comment: `If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, count) Then`  What is the INPUT in your TextBox to begin with?  Are they values separated by spaces maybe?...

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have solved your problem :)

If you change textbox2 into a rich textbox, it will now allow you to output multiple lines

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim count As Integer
    If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, count) Then
        Dim strNumbers As String = ""
        For x As Integer = 0 To count - 1
            strNumbers &= x & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
        Next
        RichTextBox1.Text = strNumbers
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is a little something I threw together to test the output

[image: The output of the program]

Comment: A TextBox can do multiple lines, too.

Comment: I didn't realise this, however, when I tried with a TextBox, it didn't seem to work. I looked for an alternative and this is what I found and as far as I can tell, it works exactly as the original poster wanted it to :) Thank you for your comment, I am now going to have a go again! :)

Comment: `textBox2.Multiline = true;`

Comment: Thank you so much! That is so simple, I can't believe I didn't notice. It now works with a regular TextBox :)